# Jmeter automatically adding <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> tag

Tags: xml, soap, jmeter

I am trying to push a SOAP request through JMeter and I am seeing error "Unable to parse element AccountTransferRequest - null "

```
<soap:Body>
  <ns9:AccountTransferRequest xmlns:ns9="http://at.abc.abc.gov/exchange/1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://.gov/abc/structures/2.0" xmlns:ns10="http://.gov/abc/appinfo/2.1" xmlns:ns2="http://abc.gov/abc/abc-core/2.0" xmlns:ns3="http://abc.gov/extension/1.0" xmlns:ns4="http://abc.abc.gov/0.1/hix-core" xmlns:ns5="http://abc.abc.gov/0.1/hix-ee" xmlns:ns6="http://abc.gov/abc/domains/screening/2.1" xmlns:ns7="http://abc.abc.gov/0.1/hix-pm" xmlns:ns8="http://abc.abc/abc/appinfo/2.0">
     <ns3:TransferHeader>
        <ns3:TransferActivity>
           <ns2:ActivityIdentification>
              <ns2:IdentificationID>abc</ns2:IdentificationID>
```

I am assuming it could be because of the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` tag is getting added automatically in JMeter.

Can someone please advise on how to make JMeter not add this tag when sending the request?

My Request:

[image]

In the response I see  added.

My headers for the request are

```
 [no cookies]

Request Headers:
SOAPAction: ""
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Length: 24294
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't add anything to the requests (given you properly configure it)

If you put your SOAP payload into the Body Data tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler:

[image]

You will be able to see that JMeter sends the body "as it is" using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

[image]

So double check your JMeter configuration. The common mistake is that users forget to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) and add proper [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and [SOAPAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee301987(v=sql.105).aspx) headers.

Check out [Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html) article for example setup.

Comment: I have edited my question to include images now.
I am positive that I am passing the needed headers in my request and still see the xml version tag being appended to the request.